# Install Crossbar 0.12 from PPA on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wamp, crossbar

I am using the  [Ubuntu PPA for Crossbar](http://crossbar.io/docs/Installation-on-Ubuntu/) and am running `0.11.1`. I need the option to use certificate chains which does not seem to be available in this version; is there an easy mechanism to upgrade at this point either using the PPA or copying files manually? I've tried the other Pypy based setups before and haven't been confident about running them in production.

Comment: Does @oberstet know how to fix this?

Comment: We will be releasing packages for 0.12 shortly. Otherwise: The packages are there for ease of installation, there is no reason not to use a manual setup in production.

Comment: @gzost is it possible to download a release from GitHub and copy the files over the existing install from a PPA? Thanks for your help

Comment: You can download from GitHub and then try "make install" (should work on *nix).